# Word describing an object or image that has the appearance of that object?

Tags: word-request

[image: fake 'ectoplasm' picture of Eva Carrière]

How would you say this in idiomatic English? I am looking for a word that describes something like the thing in the picture, and not the specific word ectoplasm.

Comment: That is a famous 1912 fake 'ectoplasm' picture of Eva Carrière. The thing that looks like a face is not a spiritual manifestation. It was made out of a newspaper portrait, chewed paper, and cardboard. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Please tell us in more detail precisely what idea you want to express with your sentence. Using the definite article "the" implies you are talking about a definite, already-known thing or something which has previously been discussed. Saying "*the* flat wrinkly part of someone's face" sounds like that part of the human face is something normal, and well-known to your audience.

Comment: Do you mean the **skin** of someone's face? I don't understand what "the flat wrinkly part" means.

Comment: just a generic word or phrase for something that looks like that.

Comment: @Sayaman I believe you are looking for ***"visage"*** https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visage "the  artwork has the visage of a human face:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say,

"This is (or *looks like*) (a) part of someone's face, but flattened and wrinkled."

or

"This is (looks like) the flat(-tened) and wrinkled skin from someone's face"

There are plenty of other possibilities too, I'm sure, but since this image is so unusual, you probably won't be able to describe it accurately with just a "generic word" or concise phrase.